# Azure Mobile App (Android) programmatically create Easy Table

Tags: java, android, azure, create-table, azure-mobile-services

I have got an Azure Mobile Android App with a SQL-Database and I want to create a new Easy Table everytime a certain action happens in my App. How do I do that? At the moment I am using the Mobile service table but it seems that there is no way to create a new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there are no APIs to programmatically create tables.

Although not as simple, you can, however, create a custom API that will create the required table files in the appropriate table folder in the  file system and,  as long as dynamic schema is enabled, that would expose your new table as part of your Mobile Apps API.